# Implementing WebSocket client in .net core 3.1 using ClientWebSocket class

Tags: c#, websocket, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm implementing a simple client in C#/.NET Core 3.1, using `ClientWebSocket` library provided by Microsoft. While receiving data, I'm passing a cancellation token with 10 sec delay. If I don't receive any message in that duration, websocket goes to Aborted State and I have to connect again.

Can anyone help in this regard?

```
public async Task Receive()
{
    CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = null;
    WebSocketReceiveResult result = null;
    while(true)
    {
        try
        {
            if (webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
            {
                tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(10000);
                var buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new Byte[8192]);
                using(var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    do
                    {
                        result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, _cancellationTokenSource.Token);
                        stream.Write(buffer.Array, buffer.Offset, result.Count);
                    } while(!result.EndOfMessage);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Need to Handle this scenario
            }
        }
        catch (OpearationCancelledException ex)
        {
            //Handle Exception
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Tatranskymedved As you can see in the function above, I am calling ReceiveAsync in a loop to continuously get the data. If I don't get within the delay of cancellationToken and operation is cancelled, Websocket goes to Aborted state.
This is what I described above. If there is something specific you are not clear, please let me know.

Comment: @Tatranskymedved I have to perform it in a loop as it I receive message from the other end any time.